# How to add divisibility constraint in GNU mathprog

Tags: linear-programming, ampl, mathprog

I want to add a constraint that a variable should be divisible by a particular integer.
I tried using mod operator but it cannot be used with variables:

```
s.t. c1 x1 mod 10 = 0
```

I get the following error:

> operand preceding mod has invalid type

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually surprisingly easy.

Your constraint:

```
 x mod 10 = 0
```

is equivalent to

```
 x = 10 * n where n is an integer
```

So the recipe is: add an integer variable `n` and add the linear constraint:

```
 x = 10 * n
```